# Checkbox filtering in Magento admin grid

Tags: checkbox, filter, magento

[image: grid filtering and checkboxes]

I have a Slider model having some associated Images (models). When editing a Slider, there's a tab for its images. Now this can be modified, to select and deselect containing images. This, it seems, is done through an admin grid, having a checkbox column (the "values" key is for testing):

```
    $this->addColumn('in_slider', array(
        'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
        'type'      => 'checkbox',
        'name'      => 'in_slider',
        'values'    => array(1,2),
        'align'     => 'center',
        'index'     => 'slider_image_id'
    ));
```

Let's say the Slider in the above image has one image attached, and that works fine. But, when user selects "Any" and clicks "Search", *all* images must show, but those that are not associated should be deselected. I think this is standard behavior for such a feature.

What I don't get is the mechanism behind those two buttons: `Reset Filter` and `Search`. From what I've managed to dig up, a grid class has a `getGridUrl()` method which is used to refresh the grid data (via AJAX). That URL mapping to a controller.

```
// in grid class
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/editGrid', array('_current' => true));
}

// Image controller
public function editGridAction()
{
    $blockMarkup = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/someblock')->toHtml();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($blockMarkup);
}
```

*But what about the "Search" button? How does that work?*

*How do other modules know when to show ALL entities, or searching for "Yes" or "No"?*

*When saving the slider, how can one grab the selected values?* Working in Slider controller's `saveAction` I presume, but how do you get the checkbox values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a **mass action**.  Add this function to your grid file (whatever extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Weidget_Grid):

```
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
  $this->setMassactionIdField('some_ID');
  $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('element_name');  //html name of checkbox
  $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('some_ID', array(
    'label'=> __('Some Label'),
    'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/*/doSomething'),   //an action defined in the controller
    'selected' => 'selected',
    'confirm' => __('Are you sure?')
  ));

  return $this;
}
```

Here's a good blog post that helps to explain the concept: 
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-massactions-to-magentos-grid/